# entity framework code first saves data somewhere, but don't know where

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I just installed a fresh win7, VS, SQl server 2008 R2. I run the SaveChanges() method and the data is saved somewhere but I can't see any created database in Sql server 2008 manager. What should I do? I know that the data is saved because I can retrieve it.

Where has code first saved my data? how can I make it save date in Sql server 2008, or if the data is there shouldn't it appear in Databases node?

Comment: What is your connection string?  If this is some kind of sample application a lot of them use an embedded SQL Express database for convenience.  You wouldn't see this database when connecting to your local instance.

Comment: how should my connection string look like in order to create a database with the name MyDatabase username john and password doe? Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

By default, Code First connects to the SQL Express instance (`Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS`). To have it save data in another insatnce (e.g. `Data Source=(local)`), change the connection string that you supply.

```
public MyContext()
    : base("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;User ID=john;Password=doe;MultipleActiveResultSets=true")
{
}
```

For the various ways of setting a connection string, check out [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/27/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-2-connections-and-models.aspx).

Comment: FYI, `.` and `(local)` synonyms for `localhost`.